# How to get last modified file from SFTP using curl

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl

I want to download the latest modified file. It should be a .zip file on a remote server. In Shell Script I am using

```
$curl $curloptLS |egrep '0001_EXP_$currdate'|egrep '*.zip' > $TMPDIR/files.list
```

It's working fine. How can I replace egrep to get the latest modified file from the directory?

Comment: `grep` OR `egrep` is not capable of this job. You should look at `find` command for this purpose. Check `man find` for the clause `-mmin` or `-mtime`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I need to pick latest file from all the files.The file may be 1 day or 2 day older or more.I am trying to $curl $curloptLS |find . -mtime 1> $TMPDIR/INTPOS_files.list.Getting error find:missing argument to '-mtime'